# React-Redux: sending data from Child-component to store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I create 2 components: Parent and Child.

Child-component contains the input-field, in which user enter the data.
Entering data must be send to redux-store.

```
     class Child extends Component {
         constructor(props) {
             super(props)              
             this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
            }

        handleSubmit(event) {
          // store-logic
            }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                  <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Search</button>
                    <input type="text" value="" onClick={this.handleChange}/>
                </div>
                   )
               }
       }
    export default Child
```

Parent-component:

```
    import store from '/store/configureStore';

   class Parent extends Component {
         constructor(props) {
             super(props)              
            }
     
   return (
        <div className="App">
           <Child />
        </div>
     );          
  } 

  ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
         <Parent />,
      </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("app")
   );
```

Reducer:

```
   const initialState = {
       inputed_data: "value...",
       };

   export default function update(state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'INPUT':
                return {
                  ...state,
                  [action.payload.target.name]: action.payload.target.value
               };
           default:
                 return state;
             }
      }
```

And I cant understand, what I need to add in this code to finally provide sending data from Child-component to store.

Leaning different articles, I come to a conclusion, that I need to use mapStateToProps and connect(). But where I able to use this functions - in Parent or Child?

Answer (score 1):

In order to save something in store you'll have to use *mapDispatchToProps* method with *connect* function

- *mapStateToProps* - allows to inject data from store into the component props
- *mapDispatchToProps* - allows to inject *action dispatchers* into the component props
- *connect* - connects component to the store

You can connect *Parent* component and pass dispatcher as a prop to the *Child* or connect *Child* component and dispatch action directly from it. It depends on the functionality that you want to provide in the *Parent* and in the *Child* components.

Example for child component:

```js
// inside child component code
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    this.props.submitToStore(event);
}

// code to connect Child component
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // this will be injected in child component props
    submitToStore: (input) => dispatch({ type: 'INPUT', payload: input }),
});

// connect child component to the store
// first argument here is for mapStateToProps but we don't have any so it will be null
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Child)
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me clarify one point -  May be  "export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Child)"  ?

Comment: sorry it was my mistake, it should be like you wrote, I will update my answer.
First argument in ```connect``` is for ```mapStateToProps``` and second is for ```mapDispatchToProps```.